# I want matInput to not display error when touched but with no content

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there an easy way so that my matInput not get error color when the input field was touched but has no content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `errorStateMatcher` input ([MatInput](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api#MatInput)). In `isErrorState` method from `ErrorStateMatcher` interface you can define when mat-error should be visible.

```
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null): boolean {
   if (!control) {
    return false;
   }

   return control.touched && control.value;
  }
```

Another way is fix your validator because I think that you wrote it on your own.

```
customValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  if (!control.value) {
    return null; // this condition does not validate your control when it does not have value
  }

  ...
 }
```